# What's the sort order for answers?

Tags: support, sorting

I thought the sort order was

1. accepted
2. votes
3. random

but on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842322/can-i-recover-from-panic-handle-the-error-then-panic-again-and-keep-the-origin/34843111#34843111), my 3-vote answer is higher up than the 1-vote accepted answer posted by the question author.

What's the sort order for answers?

(Wow, this kind of question even has its own tag!)

Comment: It has its own tag because these questions get asked a lot :)